# Trademark symbol in the site title?

Tags: 7

Do I need a module to put the trademark symbol in the site title? If I add `&trade;` at the end of the title, it just gets output as is.

Comment: You tried to just add the symbole? by hold Alt and enter 0153 on num block ™ (copyright 0169 ©, registerd 0174 ®) just hope you not use a Font without support for this

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using [HTML TITLE](https://www.drupal.org/project/html_title) module

> Drupal node titles are restrictive and do not support italicized text
>   or superscript text (e.g., Book titles, trademark symbols). The HTML
>   Title module allows a limited set of HTML markup (em, sub, sup, b, i,
>   strong, cite, code, bdi, wbr) to be used in node titles. It filters
>   all other markup from titles to prevent XSS vulnerabilities or
>   irrational nesting (e.g., links within links).